# $R/I$ is not Noetherian. Prove that $I$ is a prime ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$, maximal with respect to the property that $R/I$ is not Noetherian. Prove that $I$ is a prime ideal.

I need some hints to start.

Comment: This is somehow standard and if try to look at similar questions solved on this site certainly will find the right tools.

Comment: $R/I$ is not a noetherian *ring* or not a Noetherian *$R$-module*?

Comment: Even if it doesn't make a difference in the end, ideally it's good to ensure question statements are as clear as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a,b\in R$ such that $ab\in I$. Suppose that $a\notin I$ and $b\notin I$. Then $I\subsetneq (I:a)$ and $I\subsetneq I+(a)$. We have $R/(I:a)\cong (I+(a))/I$, so $R/(I:a)$ is a noetherian ring, or equivalently, a noetherian $R$-module. On the other side, $\frac{R/I}{(I+(a))/I}\cong R/(I+(a))$ is also noetherian, and thus you have got an $R$-submodule and a factor module of $R/I$ which are both noetherian, so $R/I$ is a noetherian $R$-module, that is, a noetherian ring, a contradiction.

Comment: Suppose the problem is changed to say that $I$ is maximal with respect to the property that $R/I$ is Noetherian, then still the conclusion holds, right?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $AB \subseteq I$, study the $R$-module $(A+I)/I$

Comment: Can you give me some more details?